# Schur Bundle of Smooth Manifold

Tags: smooth-manifolds, cotangent-bundles, schur-functors

I've seen hints at the following result:

Let $M$ be a 3-dimensional manifold and let $T := T^*M$ be the cotangent bundle. By Schur-Weyl Duality, the 3rd tensor product can be written as follows:
$$T^{\otimes 3} = \mathrm{Sym}^3(T) \oplus \mathrm{Alt}^3(T) \oplus S_{\lambda}(T^{\otimes 3})$$
where $\lambda$ is the partition $3=1+2$. What geometric information does $S_{\lambda}$ give? I've heard reference that certain curvature tensors may live in this bundle, though I'm not sure.

For a smooth manifold of dimension $n$, what geometric results are there on the various Schur Functions $S_{\lambda}(T^{\otimes n})$?

Comment: I don't know a geometric interpretation, but you need two copies of that rep.

Comment: Which representation? Why do I need two?